# Python re.sub not returning expected string of int

Tags: python, regex

I would like to left pad zeros to the number in a string. For example, the string

> hello120_c

padded to 5 digits should become

> hello00120_c

I would like to use `re.sub` to make the replacement. Here is my code:

```
>>> re.sub('(\d+)', r'\1'.zfill(5), 'hello120_c')
```

which returns

```
>>> 'hello000120_c'
```

which has 6 digits rather than 5. Checking `'120'.zfill(5)` alone gives `'00120'`. Also, `re.findall` appears to confirm the regular expression is matching the full `'120'`.

What is causing `re.sub` to act differently?

Comment: You are `zfill`ing _before_ the replacement. Your code is equivalent to `re.sub('(\d+)', r'000\1', 'hello120_c')`. You have to use a callback, as in Wiktor's answer, to defer the filling to when you actually have the match.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks for the explanation :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the backreference directly. Use a lamda:

```
re.sub(r'\d+', lambda x: x.group(0).zfill(5), 'hello120_c')
# => hello00120_c
```

Also, note that you do not need a capturing group since you can access the matched value via `.group(0)`. Also, note the `r'...'` (raw string literal) used to declare the regex.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/N5AUKd):

```
import re
res = re.sub(r'\d+', lambda x: x.group(0).zfill(5), 'hello120_c')
print(res)
```